# Program a "No Photos In Albums" screen

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiview

Is there a way to access this screen and edit it for your own program?
[image]

Id want to change the "No Photos" text label. I already know how to edit the "albums" label, because I already built my UINavigation Controller.
I guess mainly I want to know if this screen is usable or accessible to developers.

EDIT:
I don't want to access albums or the photo application from my program. I just want that image of the stacking photos in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can make your own one very easily. Just have a `UIImageView` with a similar image (READ: do not copy, as it is presumably copyright) and then add `UILabel`s with the font color set to what you want and in the right place.

Comment: I figured thats what path I would have to take.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe you can change that.

Answer based on EDIT:  You can't use Apple's art without permission. Why not just make it yourself, it's just two boxes.